# appendParagraph - Adding Blank Space on the First Line

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google Apps Script and trying to generate a document using Excel Data.
I am able to successfully create the document and add tables and paragraphs.

I see some odd behavior with appendParagraph.
It adds a space (blank like) when adding the first paragraph. The the paragraphs that follow are fine.

I tried replacing the new line (\n) with '', but did not work.

Any suggestion how to get rid of the line or add a paragraph without the blank line for the first paragraph (Sample Code below).

```
  titleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER
  titleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 19
  titleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Arial'
  titleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true
  const compTitle = cell.appendParagraph('TITLE PARAGRAPH')
  compTitle.setAttributes(titleStyle)
  
  const contentStyle = {}
  contentStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER
  contentStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 11
  contentStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Arial'
  contentStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false
  const content = cell.appendParagraph('CONTENT PARAGRAPH')
  content.setAttributes(contentStyle)
```

Comment: All documents start with one paragraph already there.  The point being that you can never delete all of the body children.

Comment: For your purpose, as far as I can tell, it would be sufficient just to replace the contents of the first paragraph. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As Cooper mentioned, your documents start off with a blank paragraph. If you want to remove it programmatically, run the following function:

```js
function removeEmptyPara() {
  const paras = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();
  const firstPara = paras[0];
  if (paras.length > 1 && !firstPara.getText()) firstPara.removeFromParent()
}
```

Let me know if this helps.